# react-native-reanimated breaks my app when using React Navigation Drawer

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have a React Native app where I am using React Navigation and React Native Paper. On my first screen I am using a Stack Navigator, but in another screen I want to use a Drawer Navigator. I installed all necessary dependencies, but I am getting an error whenever I uncomment the line that reads:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: Failed to create a worklet.  
Did you forget to add Reanimated Babel plugin in babel.config.js?  
See installation docs at  
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation#babel-plugin., js engine: hermes
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "fast_pass_fe_mobile",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-aria/ssr": "^3.7.0",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.72.1",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
        "react-native-paper": "^5.9.1",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.22.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
        "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
        "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.7",
        "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
        "eslint": "^8.19.0",
        "jest": "^29.2.1",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.5",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
        "typescript": "4.8.4"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=16"
    }
}
```

I have tried using previous versions of react-native-reanimated from 1 to 2 and that has not solved the issue. I followed the instructions concerning the babel.config.js file and here it is:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    env: {
        production: {
            plugins: [
                'react-native-paper/babel',
                'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you downgrade react-native-animated version to v2?

Comment: remove node_modules folder then run  yarn install then run yarn start --reset-cache

Comment: env: {
        production: { ??

Comment: i'm not sure if you must have that env object. Try this configuration: `module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
`